# How to get the object's field key after converting via GSON?

Tags: java, android, gson

```
    public class POIItem {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("phone")
    private String phone;
    private String title;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
}
```

this is my json:

```
{"id":"1","title":"testTitle","address":"testAdress","phone":"00990434343"}
```

but my recyclerView consists of CardView ,which has 2 fields
Title :Value
where 
first itemView Id :1, secondView Title :"testTitle" ............

I need to represent each field as line in  listview,where the item of listview have title ,which is the method name ,"Phone" and the value is getPhone(). How to get the method name or the SerializedName of each field
and to get the method counts

I need only to have value,but also key ,via GSON

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking, does your json data proeprtiy names change every time? if you can update the question with a json sample and the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the `gson` object, can I suggest you to convert your `gson` to `java.util.Map` as follows:-

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();       
Map<String,Object> map = gson.fromJson(json,type);
```

While you are in possession of `java.util.Map`, you can easily use both `key` and `value` that come to you via `gson`.

```
//iterate the map in order to get field name and value
Set<String> fieldSet = map.keySet();
for (String fieldName : fieldSet) {
    Object fieldValue = map.get(fieldName);
    System.out.println("field name = "+fieldName+", field value: "+fieldValue);
}
```

Comment: I could get what you mean ,how I could  put as key ,the object field key?

Comment: You do not put key and value. If you have `gson` and you need both field name and value, you convert that `gson` into `java.util.Map`. You do not put key-value. You iterate the `Map` and you get every field name and corresponding value.  You only have to iterate the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@SerializedName` when the field's name is different at server-side (returned JSON). Use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit).

Comment: I know it, I need to get key ,how?

Comment: @I.S.S.J you mean the key whose sent from server before converting to Java object? or the object's field key after converting? If you want better help, please update your question with what you want to do with the key.

Comment: I have update question
I need the object's field key after converting

Comment: @I.S.S.J So, you want to get the field name beside of its value, but why? You have to search about reflection and getting java object field name.

Comment: because in the view it displays not only value ,but also key

Comment: @I.S.S.J I don't get why you really want to show the key to users! but I cannot help you more, sorry.